# php - regex to extract phone numbers from a string

Tags: php, regex

i am having a small problem with my regex which i use to extract italian phone numbers from a string

```
<?php
$output = "+39 3331111111";
preg_match_all('/^((00|\+)39[\. ]??)??3\d{2}[\. ]??\d{6,7}$/',$output,$matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

it works correctly if the `$output` is just the telephone number but if i change the output with a more complex string like:

(eg. `$output = "hello this is my number +39 3331111111 how are you?";`)

it will not extract the number, how can i change my regex to extract the number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the anchors and add word boundaries `\b` at the right places:

```
((\b00|\+)39[\. ]??)??3\d{2}[\. ]??\d{6,7}\b
   ^                                       ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI8cA3/1).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/kwaRIS):

```
$output = "hello this is my number +39 3331111111 how are you?";
preg_match_all('/((\b00|\+)39[\. ]??)??3\d{2}[\. ]??\d{6,7}\b/',$output,$matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
```

You can also use non-capturing groups (to "clean" the output a bit) and a greedy `?` instead of lazy `??` (the regex will be a bit more efficient):

```
(?:(?:\b00|\+)39[\. ]?)?3\d{2}[\. ]?\d{6,7}\b
 ^^ ^^               ^ ^           ^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI8cA3/2)